# Restoring state in the onResume method causes App crash

Tags: android, onresume

I'm trying to save the checked state of selected items of my recyclerView in the `onPause()` method and restore in `onResume()` ,but the code in `onResume()` causes my app to crash.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(selectedList);
        editor.putString("selected", json);
        editor.commit();
    }

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString("selected", "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ImageModel>>() {}.getType();
        selectedList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedList.size(); i++){
            selectedList.get(i).setSelected(true);
        }
        if(selectedList == null){
            selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of crash are you getting share the log

Comment: Why are you accessing `selectedList` before checking if it is null?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix your code, you have on this line: `for (int i = 0; i < selectedList.size(); i++)` an exception may be thrown `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Alternatively, you can fix this and other problems in the following way:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(selectedList);
    editor.putString("selected", json);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    
    String json = sharedPrefs.getString("selected", "");

    if (json.isEmpty()) {
        selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    } else {
        fillSelectedList(json)
    }
}

private void fillSelectedList(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ImageModel>>() {}.getType();
    selectedList = gson.fromJson(json, type);

    if(selectedList == null){
        selectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedList.size(); i++){
        selectedList.get(i).setSelected(true);
    }
}
```